# Why number of peaks of my signal stay same when I increase n in n-point moving average filter when data is big?

Tags: matlab, csv, filter, signal-processing, moving-average

I am using MATLAB to find the number of peaks of a signal.
I'm trying to **plot the number of peaks of a signal filtered with N-point moving average filter, N goes from 2 to 30**.(I also consider the number of peaks when no filter has applied at the beginning of the resulting array) My data array(imported from csv and has double values between 0 and 1) has around 50k points. When I give part of the data i.e 100, 500 or 1000 points, using array slicing, # of peaks decrease as expected. However, when I give the whole  data or even 2000 points, the number of peaks stays same at 127.

I changed the number of data given to the filter to find out why this happens. I changed the commented lines like showed in the comment and tried. When less than 1000 data points given plot was fine.

Here is the signal 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1bkcjn5ta5q610/exampleSignal.csv?dl=0

**Please import it from 4th element to end, it has some strange data at the beginning, I have not taken them, VarName1 is the imported column vector's name**

```matlab
numberOfPeaks = zeros(30,1,'int8');

pks = findpeaks(VarName1); % VarName1(1:1000,:)   (when no filter applied)

numberOfPeaks(1) = size(pks,1);


for i=2:30
    h = 1/i*ones(1,i,'double');
    y = filter(h,1,VarName1); % VarName1(1:1000,:)


    numberOfPeaks(i) = size(findpeaks(y),1);
end

plot(1:30,numberOfPeaks);
```

I expect a plot like this when whole the data is given: 
[image: expected]

but I get:

[image: plotted]

Comment: That code doesnt look like matlab, due to the `" "`.

Comment: @AnderBiguri edited for you :)

Comment: please provide a full [mcve]

Comment: @AnderBiguri added signal and explained an import issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the problem is int8 I use. It can only take up to 127 and this caused my big results to be as 127.

Turning it into double solves the problem.